# Derivative at the Edge

Tags: code-golf, math

My preferred way to approximate a derivative is the central difference, its more accurate than forward difference or backward difference, and I'm too lazy to go higher-order. But the central difference requires a data point on either side of point you are evaluating. Normally this means you end up not having a derivative at either endpoint. To solve it, I want you to switch to forward and backward difference at the edges:

Specifically, I want you to use a forward difference for the first point, a backward difference for the last point, and a central difference for all the points in the middle. Also, you can assume x values are evenly spaced, and focus only on y. Use these formulas:

[image]

Good luck, I'm looking forward to seeing if someone comes up with a simple rule which reproduces all 3 derivatives in the right places!

EX INPUT:

```
0.034  9.62    8.885   3.477   2.38
```

I will use FD, CD, and BD to denote which algorithm to use in which spot, so above 5 points are used to approximate derivatives using

```
FD     CD      CD      CD     BD
```

And then the calculated values would be:

```
9.586  4.4255 -3.0715 -3.2525 -1.097
```

You can assume that there will always be at least 3 input points, and you can calculate using single or double precision.

And as always, shortest answer wins.

Comment: Just a nitpick, central/forward/backward differences are just approximations of derivatives at a point, not the derivatives themselves.

Comment: I don't understand what each input and output number corresponds to.

Comment: @xnor, i put a brief description between the input and output explaining what algorithm to use for which data point. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, I think it makes sense. For 5 inputs, you'd do `[a,b,c,d,e] -> [b-a,(c-a)/2,(d-b)/2,(e-c)/2,e-d]`. Can there be fewer that 3 input points?

Comment: @xnor, that's right. And, I updated so you can assume at least 3 input points.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
I.ịṚjI+2\H
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=SS7hu4vhuZpqSSsyXEg&input=&args=WzAuMDM0LCA5LjYyLCA4Ljg4NSwgMy40NzcsIDIuMzhd)

#### How it works

```
I.ịṚjI+2\H  Main link. Argument: A (array)

I           Increments; compute the deltas of consecutive values.
            For [a, b, c, d, e], this yields [b-a, c-b, d-c, e-d].
 .ị         At-index 0.5; get the the last and first element.
            This yields [e-d, b-a].
   Ṛ        Reverse the pair.
            This yields [b-a, e-d].
    jI      Join, separating by the increments.
            This yields [b-a, b-a, c-b, d-c, e-d, e-d].
      +2\   Add the values of all overlapping pairs.
            This yields [2(b-a), c-a, d-b, e-c, 2(e-d)].
         H  Halve all resulting numbers.
            This yields [b-a, (c-a)/2, (d-b)/2, (e-c)/2, e-d].
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>21</s> 15 bytes

```
2/d1)6Mh8Mt0)h+
```

[TryItOnline](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Mi9kMSk2TWg4TXQwKWgr&input=WzAuMDM0ICA5LjYyICAgIDguODg1ICAgMy40NzcgICAyLjM4XQ)

Halves the input vector, and takes successive differences, to give `d=[i(2)-i(1) i(3)-i(2) ... i(end)-i(end-1)]/2` and then makes two modified vectors, `[d(1) d]` and `[d d(end)]`, and adds them.

The older version was better (because convolution), but 21 bytes

```
d1j)6M1)6MTT2/H3$Y+bv
```

Comment: I see, pretty clever. So you take a list of forward differences, and a list of backwards differences and average them to get the central difference. Then the endpoints are fixed by instead averaging 2 forward differences or 2 backward differences (in the same spot). Since the forward and backward difference are just shifted from each other by one spot, you get to reuse a lot of structure.

Comment: Just forward differences, otherwise yes. Doing `(y(i)-y(i-1))+(y(i+1)-y(i))` gives `y(i+1)-y(i-1)`, which is twice the centred difference.

Answer (score 3):

### Python with NumPy, 29 bytes

```
import numpy;numpy.gradient
```

This happens to be the default behaviour of NumPy's `gradient` function. The bytes were counted [according to this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/8478).

Answer (score 1):

### 05AB1E, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
¥Ð¦øO;s¤s0èŠ)˜
```

**Explained**

```
¥Ð              # triplicate deltas of list
                  [9.585999999999999, -0.7349999999999994, -5.4079999999999995, -1.097]
  ¦øO;          # get central difference (fold addition over deltas and divide by 2)
                  [4.4254999999999995, -3.0714999999999995, -3.2524999999999995]
      s¤        # get backwards difference
                  -1.097
        s0è     # get forwards difference
                  9.585999999999999
           Š)˜  # reorder differences, merge to list and flatten
                  [9.585999999999999, 4.4254999999999995, -3.0714999999999995, -3.2524999999999995, -1.097]
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=wqXDkMKmw7hPO3PCpHMww6jFoCnLnA&input=WzAuMDM0LCA5LjYyLCA4Ljg4NSwgMy40NzcsIDIuMzhd)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Adnan

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 8 bytes

```python
gradient
```

Inspired by [@MartinEnder's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83556). [Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IGdyYWRpZW50CgpbMC4wMzQsIDkuNjIsIDguODg1LCAzLjQ3NywgMi4zOF0gfD4gZiB8PiBkaXNwbGF5&input=)

Comment: This also works in Matlab and [in Octave](http://ideone.com/03Xsqk)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 14 bytes

```
.OM>L2._seB-Vt
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.OM%3EL2._seB-Vt&input=0.034%2C9.62%2C8.885%2C3.477%2C2.38&debug=0)

#### Explanation:

```
.OM>L2._seB-VtQQ   implicitly add two Qs (input arrays) at the end
           -VtQQ   get all neighbored differences
        seB        get the last element of ^ and append it to ^
      ._           compute all prefixes
   >L2             reduce all prefixes to the last two elements
.OM                compute the average of each ^
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 21 bytes

```
[:((,{:)+{.,])2-~/\-:
```

Similar to the approach used in @David's [solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/83532/6710).

### Usage

```
   f =: [:((,{:)+{.,])2-~/\-:
   f 0.034 9.62 8.885 3.477 2.38
9.586 4.4255 _3.0715 _3.2525 _1.097
```

### Explanation

```
[:((,{:)+{.,])2-~/\-:  Input: list A
                   -:  Halve each value in A
              2   \    Select each overlapping sublist of size 2 in A
               -~/     Reduce it using subtraction to get the difference
[:(          )         Operate on the list of differences, call it D
            ]          Identity function, returns D
         {.            Get the head of D
           ,           Join them to get [head(D), D]
   ( {:)               Get the tail of D
    ,                  Join them to get [D, tail(D)]
        +              Add them together elementwise to get the derivatives and return
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - 29 bytes

Stupid simple approach.

```
s[_-F<Q2mc-@Qhd@Qtd2tUtQ_-F>2
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=s%5B_-F%3CQ2mc-%40Qhd%40Qtd2tUtQ_-F%3E2&input=%5B0.034%2C+9.62%2C+8.885%2C+3.477%2C+2.38%5D&debug=0).

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 62 bytes

```
a=>a.map((_,i)=>i&&i--<a.length-2?(a[i+2]-a[i])/2:a[i+1]-a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
.bcF_-VNYK++]hJ,VUQQJ]eJttK
.bcF-VYN+]hJ,VQUQJ+tJ]eJ
++hJ-V+tQeQ+hQQcR2PtJeJ
*V++1*].5ttlQ1-V+tQeQ+h
*V++1m.5ttQ1-V+tQeQ+h
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2aV%2B%2B1m.5ttQ1-V%2BtQeQ%2Bh&input=0.034%2C9.62%2C8.885%2C3.477%2C2.38&debug=0)